# Is it possible to get a remote JSON object using lodash?

Tags: rest, get, lodash

I was wondering if it's possible to get a remote JSON object using **lodash**, I've searched; however, what I've found is either you can do it in jQuery or purely in JS `(of course it can be done using Angular, Backbone.js, etc..)` but I haven't found anything related to **lodash**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

Lodash is a library for working with arrays, objects and functions. It has some basic template features and utilities but no features for making web requests.

See XMLHttpRequest:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

You can do a lot without Lodash

https://www.npmjs.com/package/you-dont-need-lodash-underscore

And if you want an AJAX library. Here's the world's smallest:

https://github.com/yanatan16/nanoajax